# Import User into LDAP server

Tags: ldap

Im Trying to import a User database which is stored in a standard unix passwd and master.passwd.
The Password is saved as an SMD5 Hash. But everytime I tried to import it into the LDAP server I cant verify it. 
I figured at that LDAP export and import passwords base64 encoded.
The Hash what I got is:
'$1$9bWfL76d$8smVGuJOil8fG40ptOlAQ1'
The plain text would be 'test'.

I tried to import it with this formats:

> {SMD5}$1$9bWfL76d$8smVGuJOil8fG40ptOlAQ1
>   {CRYPT}$1$9bWfL76d$8smVGuJOil8fG40ptOlAQ1
>
> {SMD5}8smVGuJOil8fG40ptOlAQ19bWfL76d       (salt at the end)

I also encoded all of them into base64. But it doesnt help.

The LDIF-File i used:

```
dn: uid=tester13,ou=people,dc=padl,dc=DE
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: Top
cn: tester mac testo
gidNumber: 1160
homeDirectory: /user/tester
sn: testo
uid: tester13
uidNumber: 21639
displayName: Tester Mac Testo
loginShell: /bin/ksh
userPassword:: {SMD5}$1$9bWfL76d$8smVGuJOil8fG40ptOlAQ1
```

Comment: Which LDAP server are you using?

Comment: I use OpenLDAP 2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS